# Maven Flyway Plugin, Teams Edition, undo with cherryPick

Tags: java, maven-3, flyway

I have a Maven project with the Flyway Plugin. This Project should test the function of Flyway with a PostgreSQL Database. I got the Testdrive for the Teams Edition. I am also able to execute every Flyway-Goal also undo. The commands I execute looks like following `mvn flyway:undo` and it works fine.
What i want to execute: `mvn flyway:undo -cherryPick=2` or `mvn flyway:undo -cherryPick=1.2`

Anyway when i want to add *cherryPick* in my *pom.xml* file with:

```xml
<configuration>
   <cherryPick>2.0</cherryPick>
</configuration>
```

I use: apache-maven 3.6.1

I got following Error, no matter which command i try. Error also occurs when executing Flyway-Goals for Community Edition.

```
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.flywaydb.enterprise:flyway-maven-plugin:8.5.10:info (default-cli) on project flyway-demo: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: No matching migrations found for pattern: 2.0 -> [Help 1
]
...
```

Here my *pom.xml* file:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.flywaydb.enterprise</groupId>
                <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.5.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <licenseKey>...</licenseKey>
                    <url>Database-url</url>
                    <user>user</user>
                    <password>pw</password>
                    <driver>Database.Driver</driver>
                    <locations>
                        <location>filesystem:src/main/resources/db/migration</location>
                    </locations>
                    <outOfOrder>true</outOfOrder>
                    <cherryPick>1.2</cherryPick>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>42.2.6</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My directory for the SQL-Migrations:
[src-diretory for migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1Pn1.png)

I also tried to name the versions like: V0__C..., V1__A..,U0__D.., usw

Can someone help me out here? I look also already alot on https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/
but found nothing...

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting indicates that you have no migration file for V2.0: `No matching migrations found for pattern: 2.0`

If i look at your image, the migration files you have available are V1.0 to V1.3.
Any of those values should work.

If you want to provide the `cherryPick` value via the Maven commandline, you have to provide them like so: `mvn flyway:undo -Dflyway.cherryPick=1.3`

See: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/usage/maven/

You can also check if your provided `location` for the migration files is correct by adding the following option:

```
<configuration>
    <failOnMissingLocations>true</failOnMissingLocations>
</configuration>
```

References:

- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/cherryPick
- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/locations
- https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/parameters/failOnMissingLocations

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer.
i figured out a similar way, but i am still not satisfied.
Currently it works for me with a placeholder variable in my pom.xml script.

The missing Pattern i understand now. I watched out for this, that the versionnumbers are fitting. So these Problem is solved.

I add these 2 Parts in my pom.xml file:

```xml
<properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <flyway.cherryPick>${CHERRY_PICK_VERSION}</flyway.cherryPick>
</properties>
```

and

```xml
<configuration>
    <cherryPick>{flyway.cherryPick}</cherryPick>
</configuration>
```

Then i can pass mvn the value of the cherryPick. My Command looks like that: `mvn -DCHERRY_PICK_VERSION="2" flyway:undo` , but i dont want to give maven the value to set it fix in the pom.xml.

I want to pass the cherryPick versions to flyway. So i dont have to pass in every command my CHERRY_PICK_VERSION when i want just `mvn flyway:info` for example. The command with using cherrPick should like that then: `mvn flyway:undo -Dflyway.cherryPick=2`. Both commands should be possible, with and without the flag.

I tried already to cut the cherryPick configurations out of my pom.xml and tried the commands:
`mvn flyway:undo -Dflyway.cherryPick=2` & `mvn -Dflyway.cherryPick=2 flyway:undo`
PS: Versionnumers are 0,1,2,3 now.

Both occurs following Error

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase ".cherryPick=2". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available life
cycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-te
st-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post
-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

In the flyway-commandwindow itselfs works perfectly fine. But i want it to work with mvn-command too.
I dont want that u need to download extra Flyway, for the command-window. Instead i want to download it with a plugin for my Mavenproject and execute the flyway goals with Maven.

Comment: How are you running this maven command? A command prompt, in your IDE, other? According to the linked documentation `mvn -Dflyway.x=y flyway:xyz` should be valid. Can you add the full executing command, and perhaps some more logging from the start of execution and around the `[ERROR]` ?

Comment: Don't use answer function to clarify you question. You can edit you qeuustion if you want add some information

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it! Dont need any support anymore! Thanks:)

Comment: Consider sharing your solution for future reference.

Comment: This a comment not an answer.